# Adding an auto row at the end of datatable using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I need to add an auto row at the end of the data table once the user hits enter at the last cell of the current data table. I am new to MVC and do not have much idea of how we can do it using MVC platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through javascript or jquery , i.e.

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);

        }
```

when ever you create a new row attach this function on click event of last cell ,for demo you can visit following link

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html

Comment: Thanks Tanveer for the start up. Can you please show me more code to how I could call this function in a view? Also, seems like the link to the example is not valid anymore. Is there any new link to it? Thanks

Comment: I visited the link it is working fine. just bind an click event to your last cell e.g. cell3 is last cell of row in above code so you can bind a click in the same function like $(cell3).bind("click",function(e){ addRow("MyTableName");});